# Pages, custom Bullet points

Tags: macos

I am creating a specification for a project within pages on Mac.

For my functional requirements I want to have bullet points for each requirement.

I currently have

1. this is a requirement

   1.1 this is an extension
2. etc etc
3. blah blah

   3.1 ....

---

But would like to also have numbered non-functional requirements so would prefer this.

F1. this is a requirement

F2. etc etc

F3. blah blah

---

NF1. this is a requirement

NF2. etc etc

NF3. blah blah

Does anyone know is this is possile with pages ?